# Solving nonalgebraic equations

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

How can I solve an equation such as

```
(1/5)^x - 4x = 0
```

using Matlab?

Answer (score 2):

That's not an equation, it's just an expression. Did you mean this?

(1/5)^x - 4x **= 0**

Comment: I edited the question ca. 20 minutes ago to correct this but it still needs to be reviewed...

Answer (score 1):

Try the [solve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/solve.html) function.

```
syms x
solve((1/5)^x - 4x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use MATLAB's gatool if your equation is complex.

```
function [F]=fitness_A(x)
F = abs((1/5).^x - 4.*x);
end
```

[image]

Full size: http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/4428/gatool2.png (showing another fitness function).